# WCF service not returning data as JSON

Tags: jquery, wcf

I wrote my first WCF service

Here is the service method

```
public Employee GetEmployee()
    {
        Employee objEmp = new Employee();
        objEmp.EmpName = "Jay";
        objEmp.EmpAddress = "Delhi";
        return objEmp;
    }
```

Here is the contract

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Employee GetEmployee();
```

And here is the jQuery AJAX call

```
$(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET', //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
            url: 'Service1.svc/GetEmployee', // Location of the service
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // content type sent to server
            dataType: 'json', //Expected data format from server
            success: function (msg) {//On Successfull service call
                alert('success');
                console.log(msg);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
```

It works well and good but i don't get data as JSON but as an object

Comment: What DO you get back?

Comment: I recommend using WEB Api for these scenarios these days

Comment: Why do you need it as a JSON string. A JSON object is easier to parse than a string.

Comment: @ErikPhilips i get back an Employee Oject

Comment: @SajithNair i'm setting `ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json` in service. Just curious why its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing dataType to `dataType: 'text',` did the trick...:)